# Python treats two strings with identical representation differently

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, web-scraping

I suspect it is something with encoding.

So I have a string like this

`text = " sc\ud83d\udc7bUsername` the unicode characters are emojis.

And the string is scraped directly from an Instagram bio. I am using this regex to extract the username from the bio

```
pattern = ((\s{1}sc\s*?((\\ud83d\\udc7b|»|→|~|@|:|;|-|=|\|)(\\ud83d\\udc7b)\s*)?[A-Za-z0-9]+)|(sc(»|→|~|@|:|;|-|=|\|)\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+)) 
p = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
username = re.search(p, text)
```

The above code would work with a string declared in the code but when I am using the string which looks exactly the same but is scraped from the site it returns None.

Does anybody have an idea  should I do anything to the scraped string  to be the same as the one I am declaring or do I need to add some different flags when I am compiling the pattern?

Comment: Have you tried putting `r` just before your string ? (As following : `r'Hello World!'`). Also always try to print the type of your variables. It also helps.

Comment: Is the string JSON?  Is the real text `'"sc\\ud83d\\udc7bUsername"'`?  Please be as precise as possible with the content of the variable.